# Error: Inserting a BLOB in MySQL results in null using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, blob

I've been using MySQL for a while now, but only recently I reached the need of uploading files. 
Here is the scenario: I have a C# console application running with the .NET connector, and I need it to allow the user to upload  a PDF file, and insert it into a specific table, with a foreign key.

So, after defining the Command's connection, it comes to something like this:

```
    command.CommandText =  "INSERT INTO targetTable (ForeignKey,file) VALUES (@key, @arq);";
    MySqlParameter FKParam = new MySqlParameter("@key", MySqlDbType.Int32,3);
    FKParam.Value = _value; //Received as a function parameter
    MySqlParameter fileParam new MySqlParameter("@arq", MySqlDbType.Blob,bytes.length);
    FKParam.Value = bytes; //is the name of the variable which holds the readed bytes from a file.
    command.Parameters.Add(FKParam);
    command.Parameters.Add(fileParam);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This piece of code works perfectly... except it doesn't. I mean, a new line *was* created, except the file column is null.

Here's the table structure:

```
    mysql> show columns from targetTable ;
    +---------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
    | Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
    +---------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
    | targetTableID       | int(3)       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
    | ForeignKey          | int(3)       | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
    | file                | mediumblob   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |                  
    +---------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
   3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, sorry for self-answering. 
It's just that I spent almost two days sitting ducks trying to find this solution.
So, after using various other tools to check the process of uploading a mere 105KiB file, which included PHPadmin and SQL Workbench, I (finally!!) realized I might be missing something (well, duh!).

Not in the connection string, not in the datatype or the way I inserted the parameter (there were posts regarding the way one would add a `Parameter` in the `ParameterCollecion`, and they conflicted in `Add(new Parameter)` and `AddWithValue(paramName,value)`. Both works) , and definitely *not*  the max_allowed_packet setting . Again, it was "crashing" in a 105 KiB file!

So,... I made a `SELECT * FROM  targetTable`, and noticed **not** only the file column was null... the FK column was null as well!

```
   mysql> SELECT * FROM targetTable;
    +---------------+------------+-----+
    | targetTableID | ForeignKey | arq |
    +---------------+------------+-----+
    |             1 |    NULL    | NULL|
    +---------------+------------+-----+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

By then, I realized that the parameters were set with a `@` character, so common in Microsoft SQL Server variables. And by then, only by then, I realized that this very character is NOT the one one with a brighter mind would use in MySQL, as it tends to point to Global/Private variables.

Solution? Replace `@key` and `@arq` with `?key` and `?arq`  in

```
    MySqlParameter FKParam = new MySqlParameter("@key", MySqlDbType.Int32,3);
    FKParam.Value = _value; //Received as a function parameter
    MySqlParameter fileParam new MySqlParameter("@arq", MySqlDbType.Blob,bytes.length);
```

And be happy!